# Winbond v/s ITE chip

Tags: programmer, firmware, laptop, motherboard

My ASUS motherboard has both a winbond 25q64fvsig and a it8995e-128 chip. In a repair shop in a country I was at the time, they flashed the wrong ASUS BIOS version. I tried flashing the right version but both built-in ezflash and windows winflash (with /force parameter) refuse to flash it, giving a warning that the BIOS version is not correct for the device model. Since that time I'm experiencing graphics drivers failing to run on Linux. My first question is:

Can this wrong version of BIOS cause such drivers issue?

My second question is:

What is the function of each of those chips and to which one is the UEFI binary flashed when flashing?

Which leads to third Question:

Can a programmer dongle be used to fix the wrong UEFI version? If so, would the UEFI file from the ASUS website be good for such purpose?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The 25q64 is the flash chip that holds the bios. It uses a SPI interface. If you are able to remove the chip from the board and connect it to a standalone SPI programmer you can flash it with the bios file from the asus website.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm thinking of buying an interface. Worse case will be good learning :)

Comment: Why not simply update the BIOS with an USB stick? Have you downloaded the latest BIOS and read manual how to update it?

Comment: Oh, forgot to write it. Both asus official tools EZflash and winflash (even using /force parameter) refuse to flash it with a warning that this file is not good for this model of laptop.

Comment: This is a question about your laptop and bios, not an engineering design question about working with a flash chip.  As such it is *off topic* here.  Asking where you could ask this is also off topic; SE is not intended to satisfy every need, but only to handle the sort of questions which it can handle well.  There's an entire rest of the Internet and search engines for the rest.

Comment: Seems like you didn't understand the scope of my question. I am indeed asking for technical information on the components involved, applied to a practical scenario, because I want to use the laptop to experiment and learn If I had found the information on google I would have not asked the question here. In any case, if every beginner question were to be dismissed because it's not up to the level of the experts, sites like SE would be meaningless. Never saw questions as "difference between variable declaration with let and var" dismissed as "off topic" & "go FYS and google it" in StackOverflow.